# by passing Linux proxy

Tags: http-proxy

I have 100 PCs with A MCfee Virus for Two Years warranty. All the PCs are connected through REDHAT Linux Proxy server, I am unable to Anti Virus Updation through Linux Proxy to Windows Clients. There is no proxy settings available to the MCfee Virus on PC clients. How to Solve. Kindly help please

Comment: How is the proxy server setup?  Do you have to configure the browser to use it?  What browser are you using?  Have you configured the IE proxy settings via a policy?  Can you make an exception on your firewall rule to permit traffic to McAfee?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the proxy (and maybe firewall) to allow the connection to McAfee site.

Answer (score 0):

[This FAQ](http://service.mcafee.com/FAQDocument.aspx?lc=1033&id=TS100291) from 2007 says it is possible if you do not require a username and password to use the proxy, but you have to install a patch downloaded from there.  [This thread](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/17976) from early 2009 also points to that patch, but says that authentication support was being planned for 2010.

Now that it's 2011, I do not know if this is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following rule into your file.

iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j ACCEPT

change xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx to your pc ip.